# Efficiently read data files where columns are arranged in rows

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a csv-like datafile that looks like the following, where the "columns" of data are arranged as rows:

```
col1,1.1,1.2,3.3
col2,A,B,C
col3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
col4,1,2,3
col5,1,2,3
col6,1,2,3
col7,1,2,3
col8,1,2,3
col9,1,2,3
col10,1,2,3
col11,1,2,3
col12,1,2,3
col13,1,2,3
col14,1,2,3
col15,1,2,3
```

How do I efficiently and robustly read files like this into R.  Ideally I'd like a scalable, fast solution akin to `data.table::fread` which automatically determines type of data.

For the above example (if it is in a file called `test.csv`), I can do the following:

```
library(data.table)    
dt = strsplit(read_lines('test.csv'),',') %>%
  lapply(function(r) fread(paste0(r, collapse ='\n'))) %>%
  as.data.table()

str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  15 variables:
# $ col1 : num  1.1 1.2 3.3
# $ col2 : chr  "A" "B" "C"
# $ col3 : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# $ col4 : int  1 2 3
# $ col5 : int  1 2 3
# $ col6 : int  1 2 3
# $ col7 : int  1 2 3
# $ col8 : int  1 2 3
# $ col9 : int  1 2 3
# $ col10: int  1 2 3
# $ col11: int  1 2 3
# $ col12: int  1 2 3
# $ col13: int  1 2 3
# $ col14: int  1 2 3
# $ col15: int  1 2 3
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
#
```

However this has some shortcomings.  Apart from losing the speed and efficiency of fread, and requiring the separator to be known in advance, it is also not very robust.

For example, the line

```
col4,"hello, world","hello, world","hello, world"
```

will break it, as strsplit does not know whether a comma is a separator or part of a string.

Missing data are also problematic:

```
col5,1,2,
```

produces

> Warning message: In data.table(list(col1 = c(1.1, 1.2, 3.3)),
>   list(col2 = c("A",  :   Item 5 is of size 2 but maximum size is 3
>   (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items)

Is there a better way to read data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option would be to transpose after reading the dataset and then do the `type.convert`

```
dat <- read.csv("test.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2 <- type.convert(setNames(as.data.frame(t(dat[-1]),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE), dat$V1), as.is = TRUE)
row.names(dat2) <- NULL

str(dat2)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  15 variables:
# $ col1 : num  1.1 1.2 3.3
# $ col2 : chr  "A" "B" "C"
# $ col3 : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# $ col4 : int  1 2 3
# $ col5 : int  1 2 3
# $ col6 : int  1 2 3
# $ col7 : int  1 2 3
# $ col8 : int  1 2 3
# $ col9 : int  1 2 3
# $ col10: int  1 2 3
# $ col11: int  1 2 3
# $ col12: int  1 2 3
# $ col13: int  1 2 3
# $ col14: int  1 2 3
# $ col15: int  1 2 3
```

---

Or we read with `fread` and then do the same transpose

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("test.csv", header = FALSE)
type.convert(setNames(as.data.frame(t(dt[, -1, with = FALSE]), 
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE), dt[[1]], as.is = TRUE)
```

Or as @Frank suggested

```
fread("test.csv")[, setnames(transpose(.SD[,-1]), .SD[[1]])][, 
        lapply(.SD, type.convert)]
```

Comment: Tested on some long and wide data, and is pretty fast.  Also tested with missing data, which it handles fine. Thanks

Comment: @dww  I didn't test it completely.  I guess the code works

Comment: @dww sure, it is fine.

Comment: The data.table way can use the transpose function, eg `fread(x)[, setnames(transpose(.SD[,-1]), .SD[[1]])][, lapply(.SD, type.convert)]` rather than `t`